# How to get all the associated models from ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

For example I have

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shippings
  has_one :contact_information
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

How to get an array of associated objects from Order. For example

```
Order.associations
# [:shipping, :contact_information, :shop]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Order.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:class_name)
```

You can pass a type of relation as a parameter:
`Order.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_one)`

Read about [ActiveRecord::Reflection::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html)

## EDIT

Just realised, you've asked about object's associated models.

So, having what I've already shown, you can simply do something along the following lines:

```
associated_models = Order.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:class_name)
```