# How to iterate an ActiveRecord object's associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to perform operations on all of a Rails 5 ActiveRecord object's associated objects, but I don't want to have to write a separate method call explicitly for each object.
For example, let's say "vacation" is the object I'm dealing with, and it could have many associated objects (let's assume all has_one for simplicity): agent, traveler, plane, ship, hotel.
I could do:

do_stuff_to_assoc_object(vacation.agent)

do_stuff_to_assoc_object(vacation.traveler)

do_stuff_to_assoc_object(vacation.plane)
...etc.

but that's very inelegant, especially if there are many associations. 
Thanks to [How to get all the associated models from ActiveRecord object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016957/how-to-get-all-the-associated-models-from-activerecord-object)
, I know I can get the associated objects' model class names as *strings*, or the AssociationReflection object, but how how do I get the actual *object* they represent?

```
   parent_object.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_one).map(&:class_name).each do |model_name|
      ### how to convert model_name into the object? 
      do_stuff_to_assoc_object(obj)
    end

  def do_stuff_to_assoc_object(obj)
     # I do things to the associated object here
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model name can be converted to object using **public_send** in case you fetched the association models, check below:

```
parent_object.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_one).map(&:class_name).each do |model_name|
      # assuming that parent_object is the object that has all associations.
      obj = parent_object.public_send(model_name)
      do_stuff_to_assoc_object(obj)
    end

  def do_stuff_to_assoc_object(obj)
     # I do things to the associated object here
  end
```

As per **@Clemens Kofler** comment, to avoid double iteration, we can remove the .map as following:

```
parent_object.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_one).each do |association|
          # assuming that parent_object is the object that has all associations.
          obj = parent_object.public_send(association.class_name)
          do_stuff_to_assoc_object(obj)
        end

      def do_stuff_to_assoc_object(obj)
         # I do things to the associated object here
      end
```

**Reference:**
https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/public_send

Comment: The only thing I'd change about this code is to avoid the double iteration and simply do it like so: `parent_object.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_one).each do |association|` and then use `parent_object.public_send(association.class_name)`.

Comment: @ClemensKofler You have reason, no need to include it

Comment: @Shiko public_send was the trick, thanks. However, I had more work to do:
The first ```parent_object``` should really be ```parent_class``` (reflection applies to classes, not instances), and I had to de-classify the association's class name:
    ```object.public_send(association.class_name.underscore)```
 It's working in my application so I'm happy, but I'd like to think there's still a more robust approach that won't break for some class naming edge cases.